# How to create nodes in python using networkx library by fetching data from an excel file

Tags: python, excel, graph, networkx, edges

I have an excel sheet with a set of data. Eg: AB2DE3G3**ESS**123, ABCDEFG3**ESR**222,   ABCDEFG7**ESS**281, ABCDEFGS**AG1**262, ABCDEFGZ**AG2**201, ABCDEFG4**AG1**AA2, ABCDEFGA**ESR**001.

When the hostname is entered : **AB2DE3G3ESS123** , it must connect with all the other nodes mentioned above.

Every data is of 14 characters where the 9th, 10th and 11th character determines the type of device, eg: ESS, ESR, AG1, AG2.
I wanted to know how to create a set of nodes and edges of 4 different colors depending on the type of data.
ESS - Red,
ESR - Blue,
AG1 - Green,
AG2 - Orange

I've written a program that reads the excel file and creates nodes with edges but unable to modify the node colors based on the type of device. All nodes are of the same color. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Draw a graph with matplotlib.
You must have matplotlib for this to work.
"""

try:
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
except:
    raise

import email.utils
import math
import os
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from pprint import pprint
import networkx as nx
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import pymongo
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import WriteOnlyCell
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, PatternFill, Font, GradientFill, Alignment
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
# from l3_snmp_support import *
# from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart #python2


def draw_sample_diagram(filename, hostname):
    data = pd.read_excel(r"/z/apps/prithvi/DUMMY.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None)

    data = data.loc[data[0] == hostname].values.flatten().tolist()

    if data:
        G = nx.Graph()

        for i, v in enumerate(data):
            if i == 0:
                G.add_node(data[i])
            else:
                G.add_edge(data[i - 1], data[i])

        pos = nx.circular_layout(G, 2)
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,
                               nodelist=data,
                               node_color='ORANGE',
                               node_size=500,
                               label="ESS")
        nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos,
                                font_color='black',
                                font_size=10)
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
        plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches="tight")
        print("Nodes created")
    else:
        print("No data found")


draw_sample_diagram("sample.png", input("Enter Hostname: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key step here is to iterate over your nodes and generate iterables of colors and labels.  Here is an example with the data you provided:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


color_map = {'ESS':'#CC0000',
          'ESR': '#0000FF',
          'AG1':'#009900', 
          'AG2':'#FF8000'}

hosts = ['AB2DE3G3ESS123',
         'ABCDEFG3ESR222',
         'ABCDEFG7ESS281',
         'ABCDEFGSAG1262',
         'ABCDEFGZAG2201',
         'ABCDEFG4AG1AA2',
         'ABCDEFGAESR001']

colors = []
labels = {}
nodes = []

for host in hosts:
    node = np.random.randint(10000)
    nodes.append(node)
    dev_type = host[8:11]
    labels[node] = dev_type
    if dev_type in color_map.keys():
        colors.append(color_map[dev_type])
        
print("Colors:", colors)
print("Labels:", labels)
print("Nodes:", nodes)
```

which prints

```
Colors: ['#CC0000', '#0000FF', '#CC0000', '#009900', '#FF8000', '#009900', '#0000FF']
Labels: {491: 'ESS', 6520: 'ESR', 5203: 'ESS', 199: 'AG1', 1519: 'AG2', 3619: 'AG1', 3730: 'ESR'}
Nodes: [491, 6520, 5203, 199, 1519, 3619, 3730]
```

You can then pass the list of colors to the `node_color` argument of `nx.draw_networkx_nodes()` as well as the list of labels to `nx.draw_networkx_labels()`:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G, 2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,
                       pos,
                       node_color=colors, # pass colors list
                       node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,
                        pos,
                        labels, # pass labels list
                        font_color='black',
                        font_size=10)
plt.plot()
```

which gives

[image: colored_nodes_graph_no_edges]